# Read Text from Image with Android

Tags: java, android, image-processing

How to read text from image in android app.

**Edited:**

I want to detect text from image which i have captured from camera in android.

Is it possible or is there any library to read text from taken image.

Comment: Your question is quite vague. Explain in more detail what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: I need to read text from image where image is caputered from camera..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not related to android.    If you like to get text contained in image you will need

- detect text position in image
- perform OCR on found text

This task is not trivial and requires some computing resources.   There are some OCR libraries around - like opencv, tesseract etc.  I and others also develop pure java opensource solution:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/

Comment: can you have any suggestion for implemention this ocr jar file in our application

Comment: Dude, there is working android demo project, completely with sources.  What suggestions do you need?

Comment: Sourceforge project contains sources.